# при прокрутке списка элементов последний элемент не менял своего положения js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

как сделать так чтобы  при прокрутке списка элементов последний элемент не менял своего положения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<style>
#content{
    position:relative;
}
#wrap{
    height: 105px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 180px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.two {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: red;
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
</style>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="one">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
            <div>11</div>
            <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div>
            <div>14</div>
            <div>15</div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            Текст
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#fixed").offset();
        var topPadding = 5;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("two").css({marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding});
            }
            else {$("two").css({marginTop: 0});};});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот как тебе вариант подходит ?

http://vk.cc/4MXbLJ

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите свойство `position: fixed` [вот](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)